# Crossed & nested random effects in lmer

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I'm trying to get the specification correct for a crossed and nested effect model. Suppose I want to cross `Sample` & `typeStatus`, and then have a random effect of `day` nested within that cross?

I've been trying to figure it out from Ch2 ([pdf](http://lme4.r-forge.r-project.org/book/Ch2.pdf)) of the online book, *lme4: Mixed-effects Modeling with R*, but can't quite seem to get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pdf lists an example of fitting a model with crossed random effects using the `Penicillin` dataset in section 2.1.2 (p. 4 of pdf), and an example of fitting a model with nested random effects using the `Pastes` dataset in section 2.2.2 (p. 14 of pdf).  At the beginning of the latter section, it reads:

> Fitting a model with simple, scalar random effects for nested factors is done in exactly the same way as fitting a model with random effects for crossed grouping factors.

I don't know much about your data, but from these I would guess that you might specify your model like so:

```
library(lme4)
model = lmer(y ~ 1 + covariates + (1|Sample) + (1|typeStatus) + (1|day), data=myData)
```